# Apache https reverse proxy issue

Tags: apache, .net-core, reverse-proxy, centos7

I have a React App hosted on cent OS 7 server.

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0#https-configuration, I deployed my .net core 3.1 api on the same server.

The problem is http is working but https is not working, the error from chrome is
VM313:1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/Studio/GoldStarLocations net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Here's my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName api.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/api_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/api_access common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    
    ServerName api.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/api_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/api_access common
</VirtualHost>
```

on the server, when I run

curl  -v  https://127.0.0.1:5001/api/Studio/GoldStarLocations

- About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5001 (#0)
- Trying 127.0.0.1...
- Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5001 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
- Encountered end of file
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) Encountered end of file

[image]

Comment: seems httpd cant find the cert at /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt